# ios push view with gradient background shows overlap

Tags: ios, animation, segue

I use a gradient background for my views. When I push a new view using a segue, old view slides left and new view slides in - BUT for a brief moment the old view is still visible in the background and then abruptly turns off before the new view is in completely. Overall this is not smooth.

I am using this piece of code to set the gradient background...

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = vc.view.bounds;
UIColor *startColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.75 blue:0.75 alpha:0.98];
UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.75 blue:0.75 alpha:0.10];
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
[vc.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
vc.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = startColor;
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong ? Sorry if I haven't furnished all the information.